# UITextField not displaying

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder

My UITextField will not display and I have no idea why not?

[image]

**When I run the app on the simulator it produces this:**

[image]

All help is appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of missing constraints. Add them.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. It was pretty simple. All I had to do was set a height constraint on the UITextField. I think the stack view constraints were causing it to not appear.